# Htaccess Rewrite rule is redirecting only the main website page

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule to redirect all the http requests to https:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule (.*)index\.php$ /$1 [NS,R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sitename.ro$1 [R,L]
    </IfModule>
```

The rules are working fine for the main page but are not working when I am on single product.

Also, I have tried to add those rules:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I am redirected to https but I am getting 404.

Is that caused by hosting provider or the rules should be different?

Answer (score 1):

Please, change at the beginning of rules (https rewrite moving up):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://sitename.ro%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have changed, but now I am receiving 404. Should index file also be changed?

Comment: Main page is working, but any another pages are receiving 404. This is a Laravel app.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted my hosting provider and after some modifications all the requests are redirected to https://www.
This is the htaccess file:

```
  #Reinnoire Let's Encrypt
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.well-known - [L]
    #Final Reinnoire Let's Encrypt

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule (.*)index\.php$ /$1 [NS,R=301,L]
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
```

I have 2 domains for the same website and for both of them the requests are redirected to https.